# how can I run php from command line constantly

Tags: php, command-line, cmd, window, command-prompt

I'm doing this in CMD :

`php -f index.php`

I want to run this code constantly in CMD even error happen,
How can I make force to run this command ?

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
ignore_user_abort(1); // Set whether a client disconnect should abort    script execution
set_time_limit(0); //Limits the maximum execution time, in this case it runs until the process finishes or apache restart.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rerun the application regardless of it crashing or being interrupted intentionally something simplistic like this will do:

```
@echo off
:endless
php -f index.php
goto endless
```

Put this into `foo.cmd` and then run `foo`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux sever, the following will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
   php index.php
done
```

You execute by running `sh ./test.sh`

For windows; the following as a .bat file will also work

```
@echo off
cls
:start
  php index.php
goto start
```